# JNDI throwing Servlet exception in server init function

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jndi

Howdie do,

I'm attempting to deploy an application to my new Tomcat hosting service. The issue is that I'm now getting a Servlet exception thrown when the server init function runs.

The error is below:

```
26-May-2015 12:56:48.668 SEVERE [http-nio-12937-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet Controller
 javax.servlet.ServletException
    at controller.Controller.init(Controller.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Now, this is my web.xml file that sets up the datasource:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater" auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/drkplaya_pkRater"
             username="drkplaya_pkRater" password="" initialSize="1" maxActive="30" maxIdle="30"
             maxWait="15000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" logAbandoned="true"
             validationQuery="select now();" 
    />
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gallery</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And finally, this is my init function that calls the datasource:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context env = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

            ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ServletException();
        }
    }
```

Now, this runs 100% on my local server, but upon uploading it, I receive the exception listed above.

Is there something I'm missing in my init function that is causing this error?

EDIT: It was pointed out that I was swallowing the NameException. After fixing that, I know have the following error:

```
message javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    controller.Controller.init(Controller.java:42)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    controller.Controller.init(Controller.java:39)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Why are you swallowing the `NamingException` which may contain clues about the root cause? Never do that with exceptions. Always  wrap them as root cause like so `throw new ServletException(e);`. Then you will see a "Caused by" in stack trace whereby the bottommost one usually already represents the whole answer at its own. Your question title is also misleading. JNDI didn't do that. You did that yourself.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however, this is my first JNDI application. I'm just attempting to find the cause in my error.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql server runs probably on different host than tomcat. You placed local host in your Resource config. Please consult your hosting provider what is the host of your database server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've updated my Resource config to: url="jdbc:mysql://mysql3000.mochahost.com:3306/drkplaya_pkRater" as that's the host I'm getting from my host server. However, still the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

It runs fine on your local machine because of this:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/drkplaya_pkRater"
         username="drkplaya_pkRater" password=""
```

but when you deploy same `web.xml` on host server, the `localhost` refers that particular host server.

So you have two options:

1) Either make sure there is a `mysql` server running on 3306 port on that `host server` with that particular user name.

(or)

2) Change the `url=` and `username, password` to match with `mysql` database instance on that particular `host server`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. The issue is that I've changed the connection string to:   url="jdbc:mysql://mysql3000.mochahost.com:3306/drkplaya_pkRater"
as that's the host I'm getting from my host server. However, still the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a couple of things

1) I didn't have the mysql-connector in my apache/lib directory

2) I never setup my context.xml file to include the context for which the server should be connecting. So I added the following to my context.xml file:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater" auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://mysql3000.mochahost.com:3306/drkplaya_pkRater"
             username="drkplaya_pkRater" password="" initialSize="1" maxActive="30" maxIdle="30"
             maxWait="15000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" logAbandoned="true"
             validationQuery="select now();" 
    />
```

3) I had to update my web.xml file to just reference the resource created in the context.xml file:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

4) Thank you to  BalusC for pointing out that I was swallowing the exception in my init function. So it has been changed to:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context env = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

            ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/drkplaya_pkRater");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
```

I am now successfully connecting to the datasource.

Thanks again